# iOs - iAds availablity, How often does the iAd server not have adverts to return?

Tags: iphone, ios, ads

I was wondering if anyone who has used iAds knows how often there are no adverts to return

We are debating using an alternative advertising platform when we get the 'no ads' delegate callback

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
      if (error == no Ads on server) {
              // Load alternative advertising platform
      }
}
```

If anyone has any experience, views or links to usefully sources it would be great.

Comment: Do Internet connections that are doomed to fail also count?

Comment: @Radek, No, if there is no connection, I believe a different error would be returned.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked my stats, and for the last 30 days I have an average iAd fill rate of 21.54%

[image]

---

That's why I decided to use [adWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/). Which acts like a wrapper around different ad networks.

For example you can tell adWhirl to deliver 99% iAd and 1% admob. When the request for an iAd fails adwhirl tries to get another ad from another network. They support many ad networks.

Adwhirl makes the `if (error == no Ads on server) { // Load alternative advertising platform }` thing so much easier, because adwhirl handles almost everything for you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, adWhirl looks nice.  What do you use to measure the iAd stats?

Comment: @Robert when you have an app with iAds in the appstore you can get some statistics from itunes connect